# How to check condition with the value of a key in data and also display all the nested values if present

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have the sample mongo document data as (for ref):

[image: The <code>data</code> object passed to the template is as this]

from view as:

```
data=wordscollection.find({'word':word})
return render_template('wordsearch.html',data=data)
```

In the template I have this just for the first index and doesn't check if example or synonym is empty:

```
{% for word in data %}
    <tr>Meaning :{{  word['meanings'][0]['def'] }}</tr><br>
    <tr>Example :{{  word['meanings'][0]['example'] }}</tr><br>
    <tr>Parts Of Speech :{{  word['meanings'][0]['speech_part'] }}</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

which outputs as:

[image]

1) How can I display all indexes results as

```
meaning1: def1
speechpart1: speech_part1
example1:                    //2)writing condition for this to show if exits
synonym:                      //2)writing condition for this to show if exits

Meaning2: def2
........
........
```

I have tried my luck for 2) as below :

```
      {% for word in data if word['meanings'][0]['example'] %}
```

but this didn't work either

Any help is appreciated, TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use nested for loop to iterate `meanings` also and check for empty values before

```
{% for word in data %}
    {% for meaning in word['meanings'] %}
        <tr>Meaning :{{  meaning['def'] }}</tr><br>
        {% if meaning['example'] %}
            <tr>Example :{{  meaning['example'] }}</tr><br>
        {% endif %}
        {% if meaning['speech_part'] %}
            <tr>Parts Of Speech :{{  meaning['speech_part'] }}</tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, This works fine for 2) in my question , but how to show all index results , because this shows only `0` index results !

Answer (score 0):

updated answer for synonyms

```
    {% for word in data %}
        {% for meaning in word['meanings'] %}

                <tr>Meaning :{{  meaning['def'] }}</tr><br>

                {% if meaning['example'] %}
                    <tr>Example :{{  meaning['example'] }}</tr><br>
                {% endif %}

                {% if meaning['speech_part'] %}
                    <tr>Parts Of Speech :{{  meaning['speech_part'] }}</tr><br>
                {% endif %}
                 {% for synonyms in meaning['synonyms'] %}
                        {% if meaning['synonyms'] %}
                            <tr>synonyms : {{ synonyms }} </tr><br>
                        {% endif %}
                 {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```